# Wordpress Widget - Need to list Pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress widget where im saving the options, Title + Copy + URL

The url is generated by listing the wordpress pages

The below code saves and works fine on the front end. But in the widget settings panel when you save it reverts back to select page, i need it to display the previously selected item that it saved.

```
// Sidebar CTA Widget
class SidebarCTAWidget extends WP_Widget {
  function SidebarCTAWidget() {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'SidebarCTAWidget', 'description' => 'Editable Sidebar CTAs' );
    $this->WP_Widget('SidebarCTAWidget', 'Sidebar Call to Action', $widget_ops);
  }
  function form($instance) {
    $defaults = array( 'title' => '', 'copy' => '', 'url' => '');
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $copy = $instance['copy'];
    $url = $instance['url'];
?>  
  <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title:
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" />
    </label>
  </p>

 <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('copy'); ?>">Copy:
        <textarea rows="5" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'copy' ); ?>" / ><?php echo esc_attr( $copy ); ?></textarea>
    </label>
 </p>  

 <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('url'); ?>">URL:
        <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('url'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('url'); ?>" name="page-dropdown"> 
             <option value=""> <?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Page' ) ); ?></option> 
             <?php 
              $pages = get_pages(); 
              foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                $option = '<option value="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
                $option .= $page->post_title;
                $option .= '</option>';
                echo $option;
              }
             ?>
         </select>
     </label>
 </p>


<?php }
    //save the widget settings
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['copy'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['copy'] );
        $instance['url'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['url'] );
        return $instance;
    }
    function widget($args, $instance){

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

        echo $before_widget;
        $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $copy = empty($instance['copy']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['copy']);
        $url = empty($instance['url']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['url']);

        if (!empty($title))
            echo '<div class="clearfix sidebar-content"><h3>' . $title . '</h3>';
        ;

        // This is the HTML
        echo '<p>' . $copy . '</p></div>';
        echo '<p class="sidebar-link"><a href="' . $url . '" title="Find out more">Find Out More</a></p>';
        // END

        echo $after_widget;
    }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("SidebarCTAWidget");') );
```

Comment: Whatever i try it breaks, i dont really know where to start, thats the plugin working in its current form.

Comment: I dont really know where to start, i tried getting the way ACF generates the dropdown in their plugin, but no avail. Im able to create the dropdown, just not pull through the list of pages in a loop or however its needed.

Comment: Can you consolidate the Question? The first block of code is almost the same as the second, and the snapshot doesn't reflect your current situation. I've removed my answer because it doesn't make much sense given the update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @b__ i managed to work out how to compare the saved url in the database and mark it as selected

```
$option = '<option '. (get_page_link( $page->ID ) == attribute_escape($url) ? "selected='selected'":"").'value="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
```